# My code below is working correctly and printing in python...However when I try to tweet it, it gives these errors. Could you please help me with this?

Tags: python, tweepy

Code :

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup      
 import tweepy
 import apikey
      
 def work():
     auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(apikey.API_KEY, apikey.API_SECRET_KEY)
     auth.set_access_token(apikey.ACCESS_TOKEN, apikey.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
     api = tweepy.API(auth)

     try:
           api.verify_credentials()
           print("Authentication OK")
     except:
           print("Error during authentication")


     score_check = 0
     init = 0

     url = "https://www.espncricinfo.com/live-cricket-score"
     r = requests.get(url)
     htmlContent = r.content
     soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent, 'html.parser')
     live_check = soup.find_all("div", class_="match-info match-info-FIXTURES")

     api.update_status('----Live Scores----')


     for i in live_check:
         statusRed = 0
         for ik in i.children:
             if ik['class'] == ['status', 'red'] and ik.get_text() == 'live':
                 statusRed += 1
         if statusRed == 1:
             teams_parent = i.find("div", class_="teams")
             score = []
             team_names = []
             i=0
             check_one = ''
             check_two = ''
             flag_one = 0
             flag_two = 0

             teams = teams_parent.find_all("div", class_="team")
             for team in teams:
                 score_info = team.find("div", class_="score-detail")
                 if score_info and i == 0:
                     score.append(score_info.get_text())
                     check_one = 'Printed A Score'
                     flag_one = 1
                 elif i == 0 and flag_one == 0 :
                     check_one = 'Did Not Print A Score'
                 if score_info and i == 1:
                     score.append(score_info.get_text())
                     check_two = 'Printed B Score'
                     flag_two = 1
                 elif i == 0 and flag_two == 0 :
                     check_two = 'Did Not Print B Score'
                 team_Detail = team.find("div", class_="name-detail")
                 if team_Detail:
                     team_names.append(team_Detail.get_text())
                     i+=1
             #print(check_one)
             #print(check_two)
             if len(team_names) == 2 and len(score) == 2:
                api.update_status(team_names[0], score[0],  'Vs', team_names[1], score[1])
             elif len(team_names) == 2 and check_one == 'Printed A Score':
                 api.update_status(team_names[0], score[0],  'Vs', team_names[1])
             elif len(team_names) == 2 and check_two == 'Printed B Score':
                 api.update_status(team_names[0],  'Vs', team_names[1], score[0])
             else:
                 print('Multiple teams Found For A Match')
             if(score[0] == score[0] + 2 or score[1] == score[1] + 2):
                 init = init + 2



 while(1):
 work()
```

**Problems :

Image of the errors:

[image]

It is working correctly in python. However when I go to tweet it , it displays these errors...But when I simply print Live Scores, it works.

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Which specific part is "*working correctly*" and which isn't? You have an error when you run it, so it's obvious that it is *not* working. Have you checked and researched the error message? It is quite informative, that you have an invalid parameter somewhere. Also, please post the console/terminal output as **TEXT**, to make it more readable.

Comment: What version of tweepy are you running? I can't find that code in github.

Comment: There's no `binder.py` in tweepy, and line 205 of api.py is `if sleep_time > 0:`. There's no `bind_api()` anywhere.

Comment: Please do not submit images of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup      
import tweepy
import apikey


#Connects to twitter, check the credentials and returns the api
def connect_to_twitter():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(apikey.API_KEY, apikey.API_SECRET_KEY)
    auth.set_access_token(apikey.ACCESS_TOKEN,apikey.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)


    try:
        api.verify_credentials()
        print("Authentication OK")

    except:
        print("Error during authentication")

    finally:
        return api

#Post To Twitter refer to last line of code.
#Add a forloop to post muliple games.
def post_to_twitter(game):
    API = connect_to_twitter()
    return API.update_status(game.get("team_1")+": "+game.get("team_1_score")+" VS "+game.get("team_2")+": "+game.get("team_2_score"))


def scraper():
    games_list = []
    status = ''
    url = "https://www.espncricinfo.com/live-cricket-score"
    r = requests.get(url)
    htmlContent = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent, 'html.parser')
    games = soup.find_all("div", class_="match-info match-info-FIXTURES")

    for game in games:

        score_info = []
        team_info = []
        teams = game.find("div", class_="teams")

        try:
            get_status = game.find("div", class_="status red")
            status = get_status.text


        except AttributeError:
            status = "status error"
            continue

        for team in teams:
            raw_team = team.find("div", class_="name-detail").text
            team_info.append(raw_team)

            try:
                raw_score = team.find("div", class_="score-detail").text
                score_info.append(raw_score)

            except AttributeError:
                score_info.append('0')

        game_dict = {
            "team_1": team_info[0],
            "team_1_score": score_info[0],
            "team_2": team_info[1],
            "team_2_score": score_info[1],
            "status": status
        }

        games_list.append(game_dict)
    return games_list


post_to_twitter(game=scraper()[0])
```

Comment: Yes, normally it works....I want it to print the live scores as well. Could you please try running my code at 4 pm today? That time there is a match, so l=the live scores should be printed. It shows an error while printing live scores.

Comment: I see so theirs a problem scraping the data, try getting a historical game. don't worry about posting it.

Comment: No actually my project needs to tweet live updates

Comment: Could you please let me know how I can tweet it?

Comment: just tried running it, got the same error as your original post.

Comment: @Harrithha I got it working try the code i edited